# Property Value from ascx file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, properties, ascx

how to set the value to the property from design view in asp.net, for some reason i cannot use the usual code-behind and have to set the value from design, i have a datalist which has entryid and i want to store this to the property.

```
<%= transaction.EntryID = DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "EntryID")%>
```